# Is there a way to turn off the logger for AWS Chime SDK js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-chime, aws-chime-sdk

AWS Chime requires a logger object to be passed into the constructor or the chime sdk breaks.

```
import {
    ConsoleLogger,
    DefaultDeviceController,
    DefaultMeetingSession,
    LogLevel,
    MeetingSessionConfiguration
} from 'amazon-chime-sdk-js'


const logger = new ConsoleLogger('Chime Logs', LogLevel.INFO);


const meetingConfig = new MeetingSessionConfiguration(ticket.JoinInfo.Meeting, ticket.JoinInfo.Attendee);
    meetingSession = new DefaultMeetingSession(
        meetingConfig,
        logger,
        deviceController
    )
```

Is there any way to turn the logger off?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is...
Pass `LogLevel.OFF` when creating the ConsoleLogger object.

```
const logger = new ConsoleLogger('Chime Logs', LogLevel.OFF);
```